# Selecting Columns by a string - Pytables

Tags: python, pytables

I know we can access columns using `table.cols.somecolumn`, but I need to apply the same operation on 10-15 columns of my table. So I'd like an iterative solution. I have the names of the columns as strings in a list : `['col1','col2','col3']`.

So I'm looking for something along the lines of:

```
for col in columnlist:
    thiscol = table.cols[col]
    #apply whatever operation
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
columnlist = ['col1','col2','col3']
for col in columnlist:
    thiscol = getattr(table.cols, col)
```